# Facebook Page status not displaying when created with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a Facebook App which is successfully retrieving feeds via the Graph API and is also posting content without any apparent errors. The App is an internal intranet-based client for updating Facebook Pages.

The issue I have is that when I post a Picture or Link type message they appear exactly as expected on the Page's public wall. However, simple status messages posted via my App are behaving oddly.

Statuses are present in the `me/feed` API response, and I can see them on the Facebook website when I am logged in as the Page's admin user. However, when logged in as any other account the statuses are missing from the feed.

The app is not in sandbox mode. The access token was obtained for the Page's admin user with `manage_pages` and `publish_stream` permissions, with the default privacy setting as public.

Does anyone have any idea why these status messages aren't being displayed publicly?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?